# Has anyone had any luck getting their Apple Watch show up in Xcode's Bluetooth Explorer?

Tags: xcode, bluetooth, apple-watch

I've tried "Show Device Discovery", "Low Energy Devices, and "Near By Devices". It's likely that it won't show up, but I was hoping someone might have had some luck.

Comment: I can't test Bluetooth Explorer right now but I'm curious: are you trying to debug issues connecting your Apple Watch with your Mac? If you're trying to debug connectivity or Watch handoff/auto unlock you can try [Bluetooth Inspector](https://grg.app/bt) (my app) which should answer both those questions. I've only recently brought it to macOS so there's more functionality I could add; I'm happy to add additional features if that helps with something specific you're looking for. Ping me in [chat] if you want to chat outside these comments, I'm a fan of all sorts of Bluetooth shenanigans!